# I get "Bad UTF-8 encoding" error when trying to download file from backend (Flutter Web)

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, dio

I have an endpoint that returns me a file (pdf,xlsx) in the backend. When I send a request here with the get method, my expectation is that the file downloads directly to my computer.

Also, when I run this required request in the browser, the file downloads directly. I think the problem is caused by flutter.

I wonder if this has something to do with the Response Type?
Or what are your thoughts on this subject?

This is my Header of Dio

```
_headers() {
var authModel = read(cacheManagerProvider(BoxType.authBox))
    .readModelFromBox<AuthModel>(BoxKey.authInfo);
var headerBody = {
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
};
if (authModel != null) {
  headerBody.addAll(
      {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer ${authModel.access}"});
}
return headerBody;
```

}

I used the get method

```
Future<Response> get(
String apiUrl, {
ResponseType responseType = ResponseType.json,
Map<String, dynamic>? queryParameters,})async {
return await _dio.get(
  apiUrl,
  queryParameters: queryParameters,
  options: Options(
    responseType: responseType,
    headers: _headers(),
  ),
);
```

}

**Error returning in Debug console**

**Bad UTF-8 encoding (U+FFFD; REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) found while decoding string:** ║ PK�[�TAMb��docProps/app.xmlM�=1D��q��A�Bb@�R��{/�dC�B~�9��noF�
g
. The Flutter team would greatly appreciate if you could file a bug explaining exactly what you were doing when this happened:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new/choose
The source bytes were:
[226, 149, 145, 32, 80, 75, 3, 4, 20, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 239, 191, 189, 91, 239, 191, 189, 84, 7, 65, 77, 98, 239, 191, 189, 0, 0, 0, 239, 191, 189, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 100, 111, 99, 80, 114, 111, 112, 115, 47, 97, 112, 112, 46, 120, 109, 108, 77, 239, 191, 189, 61, 11, 2, 49, 16, 68, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 113, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 65, 239, 191, 189, 66, 98, 64, 239, 191, 189, 82, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 15, 123, 27, 47, 239, 191, 189, 100, 67, 239, 191, 189, 66, 126, 239, 191, 189, 57, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 110, 30, 111, 24, 70, 239, 191, 189, 10, 103, 10]

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Change *responseType* from **ResponseType.json** to **ResponseType.bytes**